# Copy last cell value from multiple created sheets to Checklist sheet file VBA

Tags: vba, loops

I've extracted new worksheets based on a cell value (based on currency) in short I've filtered them and extracted (Since values can be added every now and then) with function of creating worksheets. now my problem is I need to copy a specific cell value from the created worksheets and paste it to a worksheet called ("Checklist"). I need to copy the last cell value from Column "U"

here's my code so far

```
 Sub SortCurrency()
    Dim currRange As Range, dataRng As Range, currCell As Range
    Call DeleteSheets
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Dim lastcol As Long, lastRowAC As Long, lastrowSrc As Long, lastRow As Long, lastrow2 As Long, LastRowU As Long

    Dim internalR As Long, internalUCheck As Long, internalS As Long, internalT As Long, internalU As Long, internalV As Long, internalW As Long, internalX As Long, internalY As Long, internalZ As Long, internalAE As Long
    Dim copyR As Range, copyS As Range, copyT As Range, copyU As Range, copyV As Range, copyW As Range, copyX As Range, copyY As Range, copyZ As Range, copyAE As Range
    Set copyR = Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) 'find lastrow of column R
    Set copyS = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set copyT = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set copyU = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set copyV = Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set copyW = Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set copyX = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set copyY = Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set copyZ = Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set copyAE = Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Checklist")

    lastRowAC = ws2.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    With Worksheets("JV501")

    .Select
        Set currRange = .Range("AB1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp))
        Set dataRng = Intersect(.UsedRange, currRange.EntireRow)
        lastcol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        lastRow = Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Row
        Range("AB2:AB" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range("AB2" & lastRow), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Range("AF:XFD").Delete
        With .UsedRange
            .Resize(1, 1).Offset(0, lastcol - 1).Select
             With .Resize(1, 1).Offset(0, lastcol)
                With .Resize(currRange.Rows.Count)
                .Value = currRange.Value
                .RemoveDuplicates Array(1), Header:=xlYes
                Range("AB:AB").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Checklist").Range("A1")
                For Each currCell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    currRange.AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:=currCell.Value

                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, currRange) - 1 > 0 Then
                        dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=GetOrCreateWorksheet(currCell.Value).Range("A1")

                        'subtotal of debit
                            lastrowSrc = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            Range("AC" & lastrowSrc & ":AC" & lastrowSrc).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,AC2:AC" & lastrowSrc - 1 & ")"

                            'copy ac to ad
                            Range("AC" & lastrowSrc & ":AC" & lastrowSrc).Cut Destination:=Range("AC" & lastrowSrc).Offset(0, 1)
                            Range("AC" & lastrowSrc).Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("AC" & lastrowSrc).Offset(0, 1).Value
  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                            internalR = Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyR.Copy Destination:=Range("R" & internalR)

                            internalS = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyS.Copy Destination:=Range("S" & internalS)

                            internalT = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyT.Copy Destination:=Range("T" & internalT)

                            internalU = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyU.Copy Destination:=Range("U" & internalU)

                            internalV = Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyV.Copy Destination:=Range("V" & internalV)

                            internalW = Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyW.Copy Destination:=Range("W" & internalW)

                            internalX = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyX.Copy Destination:=Range("X" & internalX)

                            internalY = Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyY.Copy Destination:=Range("Y" & internalY)

                            internalZ = Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyZ.Copy Destination:=Range("Z" & internalZ)

                            internalAE = Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyAE.Copy Destination:=Range("AE" & internalAE)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''



                        Range("J:Q").EntireColumn.Delete
                        Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
                        Range("U:U").NumberFormat = "###,###,###.00"
                        Range("U:U").Font.Size = "10"

                        Columns("A:V").Select
                        Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                        internalUCheck = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                         Range("U" & internalUCheck).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Checklist").Range("C2:C" & lastRowAC) '' this is the code I've got''
                    End If

                 Next currCell
                   Range("W:XFD").Delete
                 .ClearContents
                End With


             End With
         End With
         .AutoFilterMode = False
         Worksheets("Checklist").Activate
         Call countCurrency
         Call removeDups

        Worksheets("JV501").Activate
        Range("AF:XFD").Delete
        Range("A1").Activate

    End With
    End Sub
```

with this code for copying values in the loop

```
internalUCheck = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                             Range("U" & internalUCheck).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Checklist").Range("C2:C" & lastRowAC) '' this is the code I've got''
```

the thing is it only copies the last cell value from the last created sheet

example of created and extracted sheet (there are more than 10 created sheets and may add more in time depending on the user)

i.e Sheets("AED")

```
currency    |  debit   |  Credit
AED         |  25,000  | 
            |          |  25,000
```

i.e Sheets("HKD")

```
currency    |  debit   |  Credit
 HKD        |  18,000  |  
            |          |  18,000
```

i.e Sheets("TRY")

```
currency    |  debit   |  Credit
TRY         |  35,000  | 
            |          |  35,000
```

from those sample sheets I need to copy the last cell value of Credit column (Col."U") to sheet ("Checklist"). more of consolidating values into one sheet

the output file is like this with my code

```
Currency    |  Count   | Credit
AED         |    6     |  35,000
USD         |    35    |  35,000
HKD         |    18    |  35,000
TRY         |    8     |  35,000
```

as you can see it doesn't loop with every created sheets, only getting the last cell value of column U in the last created sheet.
I've tried inserting inside loop but no good.

it should be like this: ("Checklist sheet")

```
    Currency    |  Count   | Credit
    AED         |    6     |  25,000
    USD         |    35    |  08,000
    HKD         |    18    |  18,000
    TRY         |    8     |  35,000
```

every help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Dont use Select/Activate stuff. Qualify your ranges. The problem you are facing is *typical* when you dont do that. I cant walk into the details, but to me it seems obvious that the problem is due to that. An unqualified Range [ when you use `Range(...)` instead of `someWorksheet.Range(...)`  ] refers to the currently active worksheet, which is hazardous and source of headaches for a programmer. Have things under your control and specify everything in your statements.

Comment: Instead of copying each cell, just create an array of each cell then simply paste the copied array in the range you want to copy it in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your issue is you miss `lastRowAC` updating at every new sheet loop, like:

```
lastRowAC = lastRowAC + 1
```

before or after (it's up to your actual loop "twisting"):

```
Range("U" & internalUCheck).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Checklist").Range("C2:C" & lastRowAC)
```

I'd also add that your first `lastRowAC` setting, namely

```
lastRowAC = ws2.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

is prone to error since should you have no values below cell "A2" at your macro first run it'd return the last row index (some `1048576` from excel 2007  on)

it's safer to use:

```
lastRowAC = ws2.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

and get last not empty row in column 1 of worksheet `ws2`, with the only warning that should column A contain no values or only one value in cell A1 it'd return `1` either way. In this case you may want to add a check and handle the return value properly

Comment: @Anne, did you get through it?

Comment: @Anne, it'd be nice of you giving feedback to people trying at helping you. thank you

Comment: hi @user3598756 sorry been a while. was on a vacation. i'll try it now and will give you a feedback. thank you for your help :D